Can linear dispersion modes equilibrate to a diagonal ensemble?
In the literature of quantum thermalization (e.g. this review https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08790), the consensus is that most systems even when isolated equilibrate locally. That is for a local operator $O\in S^{(l)}_{\text{loc}}$:
\begin{equation}
 \overline{\langle \Psi (t) \vert O \vert \Psi (t) \rangle - \overline{\langle \Psi (t) \vert O \vert \Psi (t) \rangle}} \ll 1
\end{equation}
where $\overline{f(t)} := \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t') dt'$ is the long time average. In particular, the time average for an initial state represented in the energy eigenstate basis $\vert \Psi(0)\rangle = \sum_n c_n \vert \Phi_n \rangle $ is $\rho_D := \overline{\vert \Psi (t) \rangle \langle \Psi (t) \vert }$
which is called the diagonal ensemble. For the diagonal ensemble to actually be diagonal, there must not be degenerate energy eigenstates, because
\begin{equation} \mathrm{Tr}\, O\rho_D = \sum_{n,m} c_n^* c_m \overline{e^{it(E_n-E_m)}} O_{nm} = \sum_n \vert c_n \vert^2 O_{nn} \Rightarrow \rho_D = \sum_n \vert c_n\vert^2 \vert \Phi_n \rangle \langle \Phi_n \vert
\end{equation}
only when the non-degeneracy allows the identification $\overline{e^{it(E_n-E_m)}} = \delta_{n,m}$.
On the other hand, for the system to equilibrate to $\rho_D$ making no further assumptions on the operator matrix elements we need either non-degeneracy of the differences between energy eigenvalues or at most finite (non-macroscopic) degeneracy $d_G$ (see eq. 63 of the reference linked above or A. J. Short and T. C. Farrelly, New J. Phys. 14, 013063 (2012) for the version generalizing to finite gap-degeneracy, $1<d_G$)
If I consider a mode with linear dispersion, e.g. a Goldstone mode like a phonon in a finite volume $V=L^d$ (the thermodynamic limit is taken in the end), we get momenta $k_m = 2 \pi m / L \in (-\pi/a,\pi/a)$ and energies directly proportional to these i.e. $E_m = \alpha k_m$ (I assume 1D for simplicity). Then for every $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\vert m\vert \leq L/a$, the gap $E_{m+1}-E_m = 2 \pi / L$. Hence, we have a macroscopic gap-degeneracy (in fact for every $n$ the gaps for every $m$ of $E_{m+n} - E_m$ are identical i.e. $d_G$ is even of order $L^2$), or am I missing something? In that case, the system would not equilibrate.
Is my argumentation correct?
Since linear dispersion is far from exotic, has some consequence of this been observed in experiments?
Do you know any literature discussing this matter?
